# H2 Database - Creating Indexes

Tags: java, database, h2

I'm using the H2 database - running in embedded mode - and when my app starts up I load the H2 database with data from a mySQL database. I'm using linked tables to point to the mySQL tables.

My issue is that I'm trying to speed up the time that H2 takes to create the indexes on the tables, particularly for larger tables (5Million+).

Does anyone know if it is safe to run the CREATE INDEX commands in a separate thread while I load the next table's data into H2? 
For example:
Thread 1: Loads table 1 -> tells Thread 2 to start creating indexes and then Thread 1 loads table 2, etc.

I can't use the MVCC mode when loading the tables because later on I need to use the MULTI_THREADED mode when I do my selects. When I try using the MULTI_THREADED mode I got locking errors even though I was loading data into discrete tables.

Many thanks!

Comment: why not load data and create index after as "usual" ?

Comment: it takes a long time to create the indexes so I'm looking for a way to distribute the time across threads. Currently I am doing everything serially because of a locking issue but I will try Thomas's suggestion below.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure than many thread Will improve. If you have stats I'm interressed..

Comment: I just tried and it did seem to improve performance. I load approx 20 million records and it used to take 15 mins and now takes 10 mins.  I create the memory tables, linked tables (pointing to mySQL) and indexes first and then, using threads, insert the linked table data into the memory tables using INSERT INTO memoryTable(xxx) SELECT xxx FROM linkedTable. I'm also using this connection string:  jdbc:h2:mem:ingestion;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MULTI_THREADED=1;LOG=0;UNDO_LOG=0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might work (but I'm not sure if it's faster) is to create the tables and indexes first, and then load the tables in parallel. This should avoid locking problems in the system table.

Comment: Thanks so much - I will try that! Also, thank you for creating such an amazing piece of software :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add the method rst.findColumn("columnName") to find the indexes AFTER getting the result set of the table. rst is a ResultSet object. This is what I have used.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to *dramatically* improve H2 loading and especially indexing performance is to set the initial memory close to what the expected memory requirement is. As one example, this one change allowed an app with about a 1.5GB requirement to startup in 47 seconds instead of failing after 15 - 20 minutes. Prior to this, we were seeing GC Overhead limit exceeded and JVMTI errors.

Add the following to your VM arguments (as an example):

```
 -Xms2g
 -Xmx4g
```